# Confusion with unwrapping an optional value when rounding numbers

Tags: swift

Very new to Swift concepts and I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to convert a long decimal value type `var distance: String?` into a shorter one. This code is crashing due to a:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
let distance = Int(item.distance!) // long decimal value
let x = Float((distance)!)
let y = Double(round(1000*x)/1000)
print(y)
```

Comment: This probably isn't doing what you expect: `Double(round(1000*x)/1000)`. Values stored in binary do not have precisely the same precision as values stored in decimal. If your interest is displaying values to the user, you need to use a NumberFormatter. If you need to maintain numbers with decimal precisions for computation, you need to use Decimal. For much more on this (impacting all languages not just Swift), see https://www.floating-point-gui.de

Comment: Isn't this a long way to shorten a string? You could search for a "." and take a substring from the beginning up to 3 characters after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, This will help you find the issue:

```
if let distance = item.distance {
    if let distanceInt = Int(distance) {
        let x = Float(distanceInt)
        let y = Double(round(1000*x)/1000)
        print(y)
    } else {
        print("Distance (\(distance)) is not convertible to Int. It has a value, but this value is not representing an integer number.")
    }
} else {
    print("distance is nil. It should be some number but it is not set yet")
}
```

Here you can see this string: `"0.45991480288961"` can not be converted to an `Int`. So you need to convert it directly to a `Double`:

```
if let distance = item.distance {
    if let distanceDouble = Double(distance) {
        let x = Float(distanceDouble)
        let y = Double(round(1000*x)/1000)
        print(y)
    } else {
        print("Distance (\(distance)) is not convertible to Double. It has a value, but this value is not representing a double number.")
    }
} else {
    print("distance is nil. It should be some number but it is not set yet")
}
```

Comment: That is a great example with the if let distance makes sense. For some reason the complier says Distance (0.45991480288961) is not convertible to Int. It has a value, but this value is not representing an integer number. I don't understand why I can't convert it.

Comment: Actually that was me, not the compiler  I just explain to you with the `print(<#message#>)`

Comment: What's the point of doing from Double to Float and back to Double?

Comment: No point - I just saw thats how someone did this on stack overflow. I changed them all to doubles and it works.

Comment: IDK. Rounding to smaller number? Ask @DrewPeer

Answer (score 3):

A couple of observations:

1. You should not only excise the `Int` from your code snippet, but the `Float`, too. If your numbers can be large, `Float` can impose undesirable limitations in the precision of your calculation. So, you would likely want to remove both `Int` and `Float` like so:

   ```
   guard let string = item.distance, let value = Double(string) else {
       return 
   }

   let result: Double = (value * 1000).rounded() / 1000
   ```
2. If you’re doing this rounding just so you can show it to 3 decimal places in your UI, you probably wouldn’t round the value at all, but rather just round the output using a `NumberFormatter`, e.g.:

   ```
   let formatter = NumberFormatter()
   formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
   formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3
   formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3

   guard let string = item.distance, let value = Double(string) else {
       return 
   }

   let result: String = formatter.string(for: value)
   ```

   We do this when showing fractional values in our UI because:

   - The resulting string will be “localized”. This is important because not all locales use `.` for the decimal point (e.g., in many countries, the value ½ is displayed as `0,5`, not `0.5`). We always want to show numbers in our UI in the manner preferred by the user. The `NumberFormatter` does all of this localization of string representations of numbers for us.
   - If the value had trailing zeros, the above formatter will generate all of those decimal places (e.g. `0.5` will be shown as `0.500`), which is often preferable when dealing with decimal places in your UI. (And even if if you don’t want those trailing zeros, you’d still use the `NumberFormatter` and just set `minimumFractionDigits` to whatever is appropriate for your app.)
3. If you really need to round the number to three decimal places (which is unlikely in this case, but we encounter this in financial apps), you shouldn’t use `Double` at all, but rather [`Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal). Again, I’m guessing this is unlikely in your scenario, but I mention it for the sake of completeness.